# Do socket.io clients using BestHTTP from Unity get registered in a socket.io server using NestJS's WebSocketGateway?

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to send an event using a WebSocket connection from a NestJS server to a client written in C#. The event gets triggered when a certain GET request is sent to the server. When connecting to the WebSocket, the C# client receives the acknowledgment and states being connected, whereas the NestJS server didn't trigger the lifecycle function when a client has connected, which means that NestJS internally didn't register the client.

I have exchanged the C# client with another Node.js client using native Socket.IO, which worked out for me. Also, using the following [tool](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/) worked. For both of these clients, they get registered in NestJS and the event can be received in Unity.

If I use a native Socket.IO server, sending events to the BestHTTP client in Unity also works out. Only using BestHTTP in combination with NestJS somehow goes wrong.

NestJS: dependencies in package.json

```
...
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^6.5.3",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^6.5.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3"
    ...
  }
...
```

NestJS: main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

NestJS: Unity.gateway.ts

```
import {
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer,
    OnGatewayConnection,
    OnGatewayDisconnect
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from "socket.io";

@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: "/socket.io/",
                    transports: ["websocket"]})
export class UnityGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

    @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
    client: any;

    public handleConnection(client: any): void {
        this.client = client;
        console.log("client connected");
    }

    public handleDisconnect(client: any): void {
        this.client = null;
        console.log("client disconnected");
    }

    public close(): void {
        this.client.send('close', 'close');
    }

}
```

Unity: Socket.IO client using BestHTTP

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using BestHTTP.SocketIO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

public class WebSocketClient : MonoBehaviour
{

    private SocketManager manager;
    private const string WSGateway = "wss://***/socket.io/";

    void Start() {
        SocketOptions options = new SocketOptions();
        options.AutoConnect = false;
        options.ConnectWith = BestHTTP.SocketIO.Transports.TransportTypes.WebSocket;

        manager = new SocketManager(new Uri(WSGateway), options);
        manager.Socket.On(SocketIOEventTypes.Connect, OnServerConnect);
        manager.Socket.On(SocketIOEventTypes.Disconnect, OnServerDisconnect);
        manager.Socket.On("close", OnClose);
        manager.Open();
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        manager.Close();
    }

    void OnServerConnect(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args) {
        Debug.Log("Connected");
    }

    void OnServerDisconnect(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args) {
        Debug.Log("Disconnected");
    }

    void OnClose(Socket socket, Packet packet, params object[] args) {
        Debug.Log("Event received");
    }

}
```

In this prototype, there will always be only one client being connected to the WebSocket server. As the Unity client is not registered, a NullPointerException is raised. The expected output is to register the client in the handleConnection lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using NestJs and BestHttp together too.

I don't think you need

```
@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: "/socket.io/",
                    transports: ["websocket"]})
```

I think you will end up with a namespace under `host/socket.io/socket.io` as socket.io specifies `/socket.io/` by default, it's not a namespace.

So here your manager is correctly connecting to your server, on the root namespace `/`.

Your gateway however is listening on a `/socket.io` namespace. If you add this to your client it should work ;

```
Socket nsp = manager.GetSocket("/socket.io");
```

it should connect on this namespace and your Nest events should trigger.

The simplest solution here is to remove your namespace from your gateway, which will then listen on the root namespace.